# Combining Lists Until Desired List Is Made

Tags: python

If I have the following Dictionary of Lists:

```
{1: [2], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 7], 5: [2, 6], 6: [5], 7: [8, 4], 8: [7]}
```

I want to know the keys I'll need a full set of:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Using the smallest number of keys. For this particular problem for example it would be:

```
keys needed: [2,5,7]
```

While the order doesn't matter I want to use as few keys as possible. Is there an easy way to do this and to test if my answer is the shortest possible answer?

Comment: They keys of a dictionary are already unique unless I missed something?

Comment: How do you do that? I'm not very familiar with dictionaries

Comment: @Allen I think OP must mean values, not keys

Comment: The list I want isn't a list of the keys, but rather a list of the integers. I want to know what is the shortest combination of keys that can yield me a full [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: It's easy enough to brute force while you have a small amount of data. If the data is large enough, you'll need a more elegant approach eg dynamic programming.

Comment: @PeterWood is right, I want values, not keys

Comment: The problem of selecting the smallest number of sets which union to the desired set, or even the problem of determining whether that’s possible, is NP-complete. It takes a long time to figure that out for large amounts of data. You can look into the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is related, to find the best way of doing it.

Comment: @DanielH, Allen's answer below determines whether it's possible. Unless you add extra constraints, like no duplicated values

Comment: Allen’s and Efron’s solutions give the unions of all the values, not the set of keys corresponding to values which make a desired list (and certainly not the smallest set of such keys).

Comment: @DanielH, I mean that if the union of all the values matches, then it implies the existence of a smallest set of such keys.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I’m pretty sure that the desired list isn’t necessarily always the total union of all the values, even if it is in this case.

Comment: @DanielH, In that case take the union of all the values that are subsets of the desired set. If you get the desired set, then a smallest set of keys must exist. Finding the smallest set is a different, harder problem

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the bruteforce solution, using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
data = {1: [2], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 7], 5: [2, 6], 6: [5], 7: [8, 4], 8: [7]}
desired_set = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

n = len(data)

all_values = set(x for values in data.values() for x in values)
if all_values.issuperset(desired_set):
    print("There must be a solution...")
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        for combination in combinations(data, i):
            values = set(x for key in combination for x in data[key])
            if values.issuperset(desired_set):
                print("FOUND!")
                print("Keys needed : %r" % list(combination))
                print("Values : %r" % list(values))
                quit()
else:
    print "Not possible. Not even trying"
```

It outputs:

```
FOUND!
Keys needed : [2, 4, 5, 7]
Values : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Worst case complexity is `O(2**n)` though, so don't use it on big datasets!

Note that you need `4` as key to get `7` as value.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without importing combinations?

Comment: @Judeisobscure: There a probably more efficient solutions to get a good approximation of the optimum solution. To find the optimum solution, I'm not sure there's a much better way than just checking all the combinations. This problem is hard.

Comment: I'm trying to use this with combinations, it says TypeError: object of type 'Matrix' has no len() is that because I have a list of lists?

Comment: @Judeisobscure: Probably. Your question mentioned a dict of lists, and I wrote the code for your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the keys in order, you can call sorted() directly on the dictionary.

```
some_dict = {1: [2], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 7], 5: [2, 6], 6: [5], 7: [8, 4], 8: [7]}

keys = sorted(some_dict)
print(keys)
```

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

If, on the other hand, you want all the unique VALUES in the dictionary in sorted order, you should sort a set.

```
values = sorted({x for key in some_dict for x in some_dict[key]})
print(values)
```

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

I don't know why you would want to use the shortest possible number of keys, but you can do so as follows.

```
wanted = set(range(1, 9))
seen = set()
for key in some_dict:
    seen |= set(some_dict[key])
    if seen == wanted:
        break
```

Comment: This seems pretty concise, thank you. How do I get this to return the particular keys needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean values instead of keys, here you go.

```
d = {1: [2], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 7], 5: [2, 6], 6: [5], 7: [8, 4], 8: [7]}
#get the values from all elements and use a set to remove duplicate and then use sum to flatten the list.
list(set(sum(d.values(),[])))
Out[806]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```